# how to convert List of map to json in java

Tags: java, json, collections, jersey, gson

//please find the code below .I am not able to convert map into json  object

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("readCsv")
public @ResponseBody String readCsvservice(@Context ServletContext servletContext) throws Exception {

    String csvFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/branch_profitability.csv";
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    HashMap<String, String> branch = new HashMap<>();

    List<Map> branchList = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            branch.put("Zone", country[0]);
            branch.put("State", country[1]);
            branch.put("City", country[2]);
            branch.put("Location", country[3]);
            branch.put("brach", country[4]);
            branch.put("Employee", country[5]);
            branch.put("EOP", country[6]);
            branchList.add(branch);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // try1
    String jsonMap = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(branchList);

    // try2
    String json = new Gson().toJson(branchList);

    return json;

}
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: I have commented try1 and try2 this i used then also i am not able to convert  List <Map> into json

Comment: It should work, giving you an array of JSON-Objects. Is it not in the format you would expect? Do you get an exception?

Comment: i am not  even getting any exception .

Comment: Then how do you know it fails? Give us something to work with :D

Comment: it is not getting converted to json

Comment: its not getting converted to json ....Following output i am getting after printing  map object                                                                                            [
  {
    Employee=59.0,
    Zone=East,
    State=WestBengal,
    EOP=419376.0,
    City=Siliguri,
    brach=NanakComplex,
    Location=SevokeRoad
  },
  {
    Employee=59.0,
    Zone=East,
    State=WestBengal,
    EOP=419376.0,
    City=Siliguri,
    brach=NanakComplex,
    Location=SevokeRoad
  }
]

Comment: Thats the output of printing a List (in your case, branchList). The Json representation is in the String object jsonMap and json

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you create `HashMap<String, String> branch = new HashMap<>();` once outside of while loop, but you need to create new HashMap for each line in csv.

```
// HashMap<String, String> branch = new HashMap<>(); <= remove this line

List<Map> branchList = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
    br.readLine();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        HashMap<String, String> branch = new HashMap<>(); //<= Add this line

        // fill new map...

        branchList.add(branch);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

*But your code should actually produce json of last record in csv multiplied by number of lines ,so if you don't get anything in json(not even `[]`)  it means that something is wrong with your file parsing. Edit: Not the case after [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265528/how-to-convert-list-of-map-to-json-in-java/46266092#comment79494586_46265528)*

Comment: its not getting converted to json ....Following output i am getting after printing map object [ { Employee=59.0, Zone=East, State=WestBengal, EOP=419376.0, City=Siliguri, brach=NanakComplex, Location=SevokeRoad }, { Employee=59.0, Zone=East, State=WestBengal, EOP=419376.0, City=Siliguri, brach=NanakComplex, Location=SevokeRoad } ]

Comment: @Tejal if you never get json response, but 100% sure that this resource path gets trigered, than it is probably something wrong with your maven/gradle dependencies. Here is demo project https://github.com/varren/jackson-jersey-json  it works fine for me `localhost:9998/readCsv` output is (csv is random data)`[{"Employee":"NanakComplex","Zone":"59.0","State":"East","EOP":"SevokeRoad","City":"WestBengal","brach":"Siliguri","Location":"419376.0"},{"Employee":"NanakComplex","Zone":"60.0","State":"West","EOP":"SevokeRoad","City":"WestBengal","brach":"Siliguri","Location":"123456.0"}]`

Comment: @Tejal Could you point out what variable you are printing exactly? As I said, I highly suspect you are printing the false one

Comment: I think it was library issue I used same code in Sping rest service  and it worked over there .